# emacs: all-the-icon-dired-mode doesn't seem to work correctly when displaying folders

Tags: emacs, icons, dired

I tried using all-the-icon-dired-mode to differentiate between different files under dired-mode. It works as follows, and it seems that a folder should not be an icon like a file.
[image]
My system is linux, emacs version is 29.1, I installed the all-the-icon-dired package with package-install, and I have the required fonts installed on my system (using all-the-icon-install) and can find the font.

```bash
~ > fc-list | grep "all-the"                                                                                                               3s
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/all-the-icons.ttf: all\-the\-icons:style=Regular
```

Also it seems that the icons for my fonts are not colored, the icons I see on the website are colored. And it seems that the font and the icon are not aligned.

I also tried downloading the fonts directly from github directly , but it doesn't seem to work。

[download url](https://github.com/domtronn/all-the-icons.el/tree/master/fonts)

I don't know much about fonts and I'm not quite sure if there is any clear information provided. I'll be checking back on this thread every day though, and if you need any other information from me, I'll provide it. Thank you for browsing and for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the folder icons not showing up I'm not quite sure what it was due to, when I rebooted the system it showed up.
Theoretically, I should have finished the update after running `fc-cache -fv`.
The reason the icons are black and white is that I need to set this variable to nil

```lisp
(setq all-the-icons-dired-monochrome nil)
```